# when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

```
             <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(
                        function() {
                            $('#loading').fadeOut();
                            $('.adminMenu').click(function(e) {
                                $('#loading').fadeIn();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('#container2').html("");
                                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                                if(url == 'home.htm') {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                    return true;
                                }
                                $('title').html($(this).attr('title') + ' :: DNA ADMIN 1.0');
                                $('#activeTabId').val($(this).attr("id"));
                                $('#activeTabUrl').val(url);
                                $.ajax({
                                    async : true,
                                    cache : false,
                                    type: "POST",    
                                       url: url,
                                       dataType: "html",
                                       success: function (res) {
                                           try {
                                               $('#container2').html(res);
                                           } catch(err) {
                                               console.log(err);
                                               console.log(url);
                                           }

                                           $.browser.mozilla == true ? $('html').scrollTop(0) : $('body').scrollTop(0);
                                           $('#loading').fadeOut();
                                       },
                                       **error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)** {
                                           console.log(xhr.status);
                                           if(xhr.status=='403' || xhr.status=='500')
                                           {
                                               window.location.reload();
                                           }
                                           $('#container2').html('<h4>Could not load the requested content.</h4>');
                                           $.browser.mozilla == true ? $('html').scrollTop(0) : $('body').scrollTop(0);
                                           $('#loading').fadeOut();
                                       },
                                   });
                            }); 
                        });
                </script>

        when my session is clear ajax error is not called while executing. 
         **error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)**

        my question is if i clear session from cookies than my page should be reload.
      when my session is clear ajax error is not called while executing. 

when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page.
```

when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page.
when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page.

```
        my question is if i clear session from cookies than my page should be reload.
      when my session is clear ajax error is not called while executing. 

when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page.
```

when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page.
when session is clear ajax error will not check status code. want to redirect login.htm when ajax give error or reaload page.

Answer (score 0):

try get the status code in the success statement and value it:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    var statusCode = jqXHR.status;
    var statusText = jqXHR.statusText;
}
```

or try with the `statusCode` in $.ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    403: function() {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```